# Setting Azure AD Microsoft Graph Email API/Permission in Terraform

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory, terraform, microsoft-graph-api

I am provisioning some Azure infrastructure using Terraform. Included in the setup requirement is some configuration of an Azure AD registered app and this requires the following Microsoft Graph permissions to be granted (see image below):

- GroupMember.Read.All
- email (OpenId)

[image]

Within my Terraform configuration, I have the below code snippet included in my `resource "azuread_application"` block, within the `required_resource_access` sub-block. For the resource_access ids, I have used the values provided on this Microsoft page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference.

[image]

My Terraform configuration is currently able to successfully add the GroupMember.Read.All permission, but somehow it fails to add the required Email permission as depicted in the screenshot below, displaying the GUID reference instead of the actual name "email".

What I'd also like to be able to do in my Terraform configuration is the ability to Grant admin consent for both API/Permissions (depicted in the rightmost column).

[image]

Any tips on how I can achieve all of the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For permission `type`, `Scope` corresponds to the `Delegated` permission type, where `Role` is the `Application` type.

The `email` OpenID scope is a `Delegated` permission type, so you need to change the permission `type` from `Role` to `Scope`.

```
resource_access {
    id = "64a6cdd6-aab1-4aaf-94b8-3cc8405e90d0"
    type = "Scope"
}
```

Comment: That's excellent @scottwtang. It worked perfectly and the permissions did get added. Much appreciated. What wasn't set though was the Admin consent which I've had to grant manually. Any idea if that can also be automated in Terraform?

Comment: @hitman126 I don't believe it's possible at all to grant admin consent programmatically for Application/Role type permissions. For Delegated/Scope type permissions, it can be done using the `oauth2PermissionGrants` API, but I'm not sure how to do it in Terraform

Answer (score 2):

To address the second part of OP's inquiry, it is indeed possible to "Grant admin consent" via Terraform. Please see [azuread_app_role_assignment documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/app_role_assignment) which has a good example of how this is accomplished.

The relevant example is quoted below.

```
data "azuread_application_published_app_ids" "well_known" {}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "msgraph" {
  application_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.MicrosoftGraph
  use_existing   = true
}

resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  display_name = "example"

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = data.azuread_application_published_app_ids.well_known.result.MicrosoftGraph

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.app_role_ids["User.Read.All"]
      type = "Role"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.oauth2_permission_scope_ids["User.ReadWrite"]
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
  application_id = azuread_application.example.application_id
}

resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "example" {
  app_role_id         = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.app_role_ids["User.Read.All"]
  principal_object_id = azuread_service_principal.example.object_id
  resource_object_id  = azuread_service_principal.msgraph.object_id
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).